# Misconception about $\sigma$ -algebras

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ be two subsets of a power set of $X$.

One of the conditions for $A$ being an $algebra$ is that it is closed under finite unions. i.e. if $A_1$, ...,$A_n$ is in $A$ then so is their union.

Now, for $\mathfrak{B}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra, it has to be closed under countable unions. i.e. if $\{$ $A_1$,...$A_n$,...$\}$ is in $\mathfrak{B}$ then so is their countable union. This is where I am stuck:

Why is this collection $A_1$, ...,$A_n$ not a set but $\{$ $A_1$,...,$A_n$,...$\}$ is ?

Comment: what? Both $\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ and $\{A_1, \dots, A_n, \dots\}$ are sets. Their union (or intersection) is in $B$ is $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but only the former is in $A$ is $A$ is only an algebra. Right? What is your question then?

Comment: Are the brackets $\{$ and $\}$ the source of your confusion?

Comment: @drhab Yes, they are.

Answer (score 1):

Condition for algebra $\mathcal A$: if $A,B\in\mathcal A$ then $A\cup B\in\mathcal A$.

Condition for $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ : if $A_n\in\mathcal B$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal B$.

Note that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and $\bigcup\{A_n\mid n=1,2,\dots\}$ are two notations for the same set.

The condition for the algebra leads to:

If $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal A$ (or equivalently $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subseteq\mathcal A$) then $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\in\mathcal A$.

Again $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ and $\bigcup\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ are notations for the same set.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the closure under unions would be:

1. If $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset A$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \in A$
2. If $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathfrak{B}$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \in \mathfrak{B}$

That is, the $\{A_i\}$ is a sequence (finite or infinite) of sets.  Does this help?